# Implement many INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, oop

please tell me best way to implement many duplicate INotifyPropertyChanged.
I have a MainClass that has 10 children, every child has six field and every field must fired property change when own value changed.
this my code but not work:

```
    public class BaseModel
{

    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public string S2 { get; set; }
    public string S3 { get; set; }
    public string S4 { get; set; }
    public string S5 { get; set; }
    public string S6 { get; set; }
}
```

and I use a class named ViewModelBase to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
in second step use a class to  implement duplicate INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
    public class ImplementBaseModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly BaseModel _baseModel;
    public ImplementBaseModel()
    {
        _baseModel = new BaseModel();
    }

    public string S1
    {
        get { return _baseModel.S1; }
        set
        {
            if (_baseModel.S1 == value)
                return;

            _baseModel.S1 = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("S1");
        }
    }
    public string S2
    {
        get { return _baseModel.S2; }
        set
        {
            if (_baseModel.S2 == value)
                return;
            _baseModel.S1 = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("S2");
        }
    }
    // other code...

}
```

then a model has 10 of this class:

```
    public class MidClass
{
    public ImplementBaseModel ImplementBaseModel1 { get; set; }
    public ImplementBaseModel ImplementBaseModel2 { get; set; }
   // other field
    public ImplementBaseModel ImplementBaseModel10 { get; set; }

    public MidClass()
    {
        ImplementBaseModel1 = new ImplementBaseModel();
        ImplementBaseModel2 = new ImplementBaseModel();
        // ....
        ImplementBaseModel10 = new ImplementBaseModel();

    }
}
```

OK finish code! now please tell me why some property not fired when value change? is a best way to implement this code?

Comment: Refrain from using the word best. There is typically no *Best* solution.

Comment: Sorry BradleyDotNET I edit it. but no this not solution

Comment: It also seems a little odd you are using `base` keyword to access property changed. Just to make sure, are you actually hitting the property changed event fire (with the correct values)?

Comment: thank you BradleyDotNET every think work.

Comment: Was the base keyword the problem?

Comment: it might only be a copypaste error, but your S2 property above is only updating `_baseModel.S1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your setters, you never actually set the value. Use:

```
public string S1
{
    get { return _baseModel.S1; }
    set
    {
        if (_baseModel.S1 == value)
            return;
        baseModel.S1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("S1");
    }
}
```

Note that I removed the `base` from OnPropertyChanged. It isn't normal to invoke the PropertyChanged event in this way.

All NotifyPropertyChanged does is cause every binding to perform a "get" on their bound property. If the backing field is never updated, they will just get the same data.

Answer (score 0):

as a shortcut, you could also create a local method like

```
bool UpdateAndRaiseIfNecessary( ref string baseValue, string newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (baseValue != newValue)
    {
        baseValue = newValue;
        OnPropertyChanged( propertyName );
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and then all of the setters would be like this:

```
set
{
    this.UpdateAndRaiseIfNecessary( ref _baseModel.S1, value );
}
```